# javascript:worker synchronization

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I am working on HTML5 web worker and I made a function that spawn few workers and return the result, but problem is that it returns the value before the worker updates the result. So I want to delay return statement until all results are received

```
for (i = 0; i < array1_rows; i++)
{
    var worker = new Worker('json.js');
    worker.postMessage(arr1[i]);
    worker.postMessage(arr2);
    worker.postMessage(i);

    worker.onmessage = storeResult;
}

/////////////////////////////////

return result;
```

So I just want to delay that return statement until result are received.
Plz help me on how to use the yield in java script.

Comment: Web Workers are asynchronous, you can't synchronize them.

Answer (score 6):

Like the comment points out - Web Workers work asynchronously (think of how AJAX works)

You can use an asynchronous semaphore to yield only when they're all done

```
function doSomething(callback){
    var counter = array1_rows;
    for (i = 0; i < array1_rows; i++)
    {
        var worker = new Worker('json.js');
        worker.postMessage(arr1[i]);
        worker.postMessage(arr2);
        worker.postMessage(i);

        worker.onmessage = function(){
            storeResult.apply(arguments);//call it the same way it was called before.
            counter--;
            if(counter === 0){ // all workers returned
                callback(result); //or whatever you're updating in storeResult
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like:

```
doSomething(function(result){
    console.log(result); //this will print the correct result.
});
```

For more information about how JS async operations work I recommend this [ajax related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593) that includes a description of the problem and how to approach it.,

Comment: but my problem remains same i dont want to print out that result i want to return that so where should i write that  return statement to ensure the proper result

Comment: You can't. Workers are asynchronous, you accept a _callback_ and you execute it when the code is done. _Please_ read that AJAX question I linked to to see how asynchronous JavaScript works.

Comment: Please, note that the attribute/method onmessage is case sensitive. This means that if you write onMessage instead of onmessage, the method will NOT be executed, so be careful.

Answer (score 2):

Use *Promises*!

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation and its resulting value.

---

#### Step 1: Extend the native *Worker* class

```js
// main.js

class MyWorker extends Worker {

  constructor (src) {
    super(src)
  }
  
}
```

```js
// worker.js

const COMMAND_ONE = 0
const COMMAND_TWO = 1

addEventListener('message', ({data}) => {
  let result
  
  switch (data.type) {
    case COMMAND_ONE:
      // Some awesome off-main computations
      // result = ...
      break
    case COMMAND_TWO:
      // etc.
      break
    default:
      result = 'Received an empty message')
  }
  
  postMessage(result)
})
```

#### Step 2: Override *postMessage()*

By overriding the native *postMessage()* method, not only can we send messages to the *worker* thread, we can send the result back in a Promise. In the *Worker* script, no changes need to be made (yet).

```js
// main.js

class MyWorker extends Worker {

  constructor (src) {
    super(src)
  }
  
  postMessage (message, transfer=[]) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const onmessage = ({data}) => {
        this.removeEventListener('message', onmessage)
        resolve(data)
      }
      this.addEventListener('message', onmessage)
      super.postMessage(obj, transfer)
    })
  }
  
}
```

#### Step 3: Use *MessagePort*s

This is not optional. Since webworkers are **asynchronous** with the main thread, we cannot simply assume that any of *MyWorker*'s responses will be received in the same order of the calls to *postMessage()*.

For correct asynchronous handling we need to guarantee that the message we received in our local *onmessage* arrow function is indeed a response to the respective *postMessage()* call (rather then **any** message the *Worker* thread happened to send back at that time).

```js
// main.js

class MyWorker extends Worker {

  constructor (src) {
    super(src)
  }
  
  postMessage (obj, transfer=[]) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const {port1, port2} = new MessageChannel()
      transfer.push(port2)
      this._lastCall = Date.now()
      const onmessage = ({data}) => {
        port1.removeEventListener('message', onmessage)
        resolve(data)
      }
      port1.addEventListener('message', onmessage)
      super.postMessage(obj, transfer)
      port1.start()
    })
  }
  
}
```

```js
// worker.js

const COMMAND_ONE = 0
const COMMAND_TWO = 1

addEventListener('message', ({data, ports}) => {
  const port = ports[0]
  let result
  
  switch (data.type) {
    case COMMAND_ONE:
      // Some awesome off-main computations
      // result = ...
      break
    case COMMAND_TWO:
      // etc.
      break
    default:
      result = 'Received an empty message')
  }
  
  // Send result back via a unique Port
  port.postMessage(result)
})
```

#### Step 4: Use *async*/*await*

Rather then just calling *postMessage()* (which is still valid and could be appropriate e.g. if no response is expected and the timing the *Worker* script has no impact on other code) we can now use **async** functions and **await** the result before we move on.

**Be careful to only use *await* if you are sure you will receive a response from the *Worker* thread. Not doing so will lock the *async* function!**

```js
// main.js

class MyWorker {
  
  static COMMAND_ONE = 0
  static COMMAND_TWO = 1
  // etc.
  
  // ...
}

async function foo (w) {
  let value1 = await w.postMessage({type: MyWorker.COMMAND_ONE, values: ''})
  value1 += value1 + await w.postMessage({type: MyWorker.COMMAND_TWO, values: ''})
  
  let raceFor = []
  raceFor.push(w.postMessage({type: MyWorker.COMMAND_THREE, values: ''}))
  raceFor.push(w.postMessage({type: MyWorker.COMMAND_FOUR, values: ''}))
  raceFor.push(w.postMessage({type: MyWorker.COMMAND_FIVE, values: ''}))
  raceFor.push(w.postMessage({type: MyWorker.COMMAND_SIX, values: ''}))
  
  let result
  try {
    result = Promise.race(raceFor)
  }
  catch (e) {
    result = Promise.resolve('No winners')
  }
  
  return result
}

const w1 = new MyWorker('worker.js')
const res = foo(w1)
```

---

[Promise - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[MessageChannel - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel)

[async - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)